# Как перевести время в GMT +3 либо просто добавить +3 часа

Tags: python, бот, время

Бот показывает время отправки отправки смс, но к сожалению в GMT 0. Как сделать правильно отображение?

```
def on_message(data: amino.objects.Event):
    global ban
    global tim
    global nom
    global y
    chatId: str = data.message.chatId
    nickname: str = data.message.author.nickname
    content: str = data.message.content
    messageId: str = data.message.messageId
    message_time: int = int(data.message.createdTime[17:19])
    userId: str = data.message.author.userId
    chat_name: str = sub_client.get_chat_thread(chatId).title
    user_id = data.message.author.userId
    times: int = data.message.createdTime[11:19]

print(times)
```

08:16:56

Comment: что содержится в data? Подозреваю, что там есть нужная информация, которая просто не используется

Comment: Вверху обьявлена многопоточность для того, чтобы обработка была сразу нескольких смс. Но к чему тут дата, если мы говорим о времени

Comment: Интересней даже что находится конкретно в `data.message.createdTime`.

Comment: Особенно странно смотрится тип `int` у `times` при том что там явно строка.

Comment: 2020-09-29T18:39:39Z Вот это содержимоет

Comment: А почему не int?

Comment: @АлексейКожевников "А почему не int?" - потому что 2020-09-29T18:39:39Z - явно не int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например если у тебя есть строка:
`"2020-09-29T18:39:39Z "`
Чтобы поменять часовой пояс надо будет:

```
from dateutil import tz
import dateutil.parser

date_time_iso = "2020-09-29T18:39:39Z"
date_time_obj = dateutil.parser.isoparse(date_time_iso)
to_time_zone = tz.gettz('Europe/Moscow')
date_time_obj = date_time_obj.astimezone(to_time_zone)
```

А чтобы просто прибавить некоторое количесчтво часов (например 3 как вы и просили):

```
from datetime import timedelta
import dateutil.parser

date_time_iso = "2020-09-29T18:39:39Z"
date_time_obj = dateutil.parser.isoparse(date_time_iso)
date_time_obj = date_time_obj + timedelta(hours=3)
```

Comment: Но это будет работать с динамически изменяемыми числами? Ведь время постоянно меняется ибо считывается с времени отправки смс

Comment: Так в чем проблема у тебя же есть переменная в которой храниться время? Сделай то же самое с этим переменным